# How to extract substring between two characters in iMacro?

Tags: javascript, imacros

The extracted string using TAG is `"67% (6/9)"`.
How to extract the number between '/'  and ')'  ? (in my case it  will be '9')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** method with capturing group regex.

```js
console.log(
  "67% (6/9)".match(/\/(\d+)\)/)[1]
);
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/qY2sB1/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

Also you can use **[`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** method here

```js
console.log(
  "67% (6/9)".split('/')[1].split(')')[0]
);
```